# Why can I save file, but nothing else with form in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have some code that is raising a MultiValueDictKeyError, and I'm just trying to understand why exactly it's happening. Everything works fine when just saving a file; however the minute I try to add more data the error pops up.

I must warn you that I'm very much a django/python/programming newb. Any assistance with this will really go a long way to helping me understand how to properly instantiate a form in Django.

models (working):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

forms (working):

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Document

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file',)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
```

views (working):

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import NewDocument, Document
from .forms import NewDocumentForm, DocumentForm

import time


def list(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)        
        if form.is_valid():
#            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile']) #simplified version
            f_docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
            newdoc = Document(docfile=f_docfile)
            newdoc.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('uploadtest.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form    

    return render_to_response(
        'uploadtest/list.html',
        {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

template (working)

```
<div class="section">


        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

models (not working)

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewDocument(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    part = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    analysis = models.TextField()
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

forms (not working)

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import NewDocument, Document

class NewDocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file',)

    class Meta:
        model = NewDocument
```

views (not working)

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import NewDocument, Document
from .forms import NewDocumentForm, DocumentForm

import time


def list(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()
        form = NewDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            f_user = request.user
            f_timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
            f_part = request.POST['part']
            f_description = request.POST['description']
            f_analysis = request.POST['analysis']
            f_docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
            newdoc = NewDocument(user=f_user, timestamp=f_timestamp, part=f_part, description=f_description, analysis=f_analysis, docfile=f_docfile)
            newdoc.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('uploadtest.views.list'))
    else:
        form = NewDocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form    

    return render_to_response(
        'uploadtest/list.html',
        {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

template (not working)

```
<div class="section">


        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <li>            
            <p><label for="id_part">Part</label>
            <input id="id_part" type="text" name="part" maxlength="255" /></p>

            <p><label for="id_description">Description</label>
            <input id="id_description" type="text" name="description" maxlength="255" /></p>            
            </li>

            <p><label for="id_analysis">Analysis</label>
            <input id="id_analysis" type="text" name="analysis" maxlength="" /></p> 

            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

Thank you for the help!

I continued to mess around with pdb, and this is what I get. Is that helpful at all?

```
-> try:
(Pdb) 
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(293)__getitem__()
-> list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
(Pdb) s
KeyError: ('user',)
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(293)__getitem__()
-> list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
(Pdb) 
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(294)__getitem__()
-> except KeyError:
(Pdb) 
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(295)__getitem__()
-> raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))
(Pdb) 
--Call--
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(283)__repr__()
-> def __repr__(self):
(Pdb) 
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(284)__repr__()
-> return "<%s: %s>" % (self.__class__.__name__,
(Pdb) 
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(285)__repr__()
-> super(MultiValueDict, self).__repr__())
(Pdb) 
--Return--
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(285)__repr__()->"<QueryDict: ...: [u'What']}>"
-> super(MultiValueDict, self).__repr__())
(Pdb) 
MultiValueDictKeyError: MultiVal...at']}>",)
> /Users/tehspacecadet_air/newenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py(295)__getitem__()
-> raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that one of the fields is missing from your request.POST.
Can you log request.POST dictionary, before passing it on to the NewDocumentForm ?

Comment: While I'm still unsure of how to answer the above question, I ended up just using a basic FormView and now it works fine. I think that the problem with the above method has something to do with the ModelForm. It was my first time using it, and I'm probably using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

"MultiValueDictKeyError" is raised because there is a field mismatch in your request.POST and the field that you declared in your forms.py

For example "part","description",'analysis' declarations, are missing in your forms.py

Hopefully this fixes the bugs